# How to stop my receive function (channels websocket) with a javascript button

Tags: javascript, python, django, websocket, django-channels

**Hello everyone,**

I am using Channels to implement websocket in my Django app. My goal for the app is to log datas comming from a RS323 link, print them so the user can see them and save them in a file.

The program logging the datas works fine. Saving the datas in a file is also working. But i have a problem with the printing part.

I use Channels to print the data in "real time" using websockets and I want the user to just :

1. press the 'start log' button
2. *It starts logging the datas*
3. press the 'stop log' button
4. *It stops logging*

**This is my consumer.py file :**

```
import json
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer

class CrioConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):

    def connect(self):
        self.accept()


    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        print('disconnected')
        pass

    def receive(self, text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        fifo = text_data_json['message'] 
        # this is the part where i log the datas but i cannot post it here because it is 600 lines long
```

**And this is my log.html file :**

```
{% extends "appliCrio/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<hr>
<form action="/appliCrio/log/" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <p>
        {{ form }}
        </p>
        <input id="id_Start" type="submit" value="Démarrer enregistrement">
</form>

<input id="start_log" type="button" value="Log">
<input id="stop_log" type="button" value="Stop Log">
<script>
    const chatSocket = new WebSocket('ws://192.168.1.201:8010/appliCrio/log/');
    
    chatSocket.onmessage = function(e) {
        const data = JSON.parse(e.data);
        document.querySelector('#id_Data').value += (data.message + '\n');
    };

    chatSocket.onclose = function(e) {
        console.error('Chat socket closed unexpectedly');
    };
    
    document.querySelector('#stop_log').onclick = function(e) {
        chatSocket.close();
    };

    document.querySelector('#start_log').onclick = function(e) {
        const messageInputDom = document.querySelector('#id_choixLiaison');
        const message = messageInputDom.value;
        chatSocket.send(JSON.stringify({'message': message}));
        messageInputDom.value = '';
    }
</script>

<form action="/appliCrio/reset/" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="submit" value="RESET">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

So the problem is that when i click on start Log, it launches the receive function that loops over logging the datas, but i cannot stop it. Because if i press Stop log it seems like it is waiting for receive to finish before running it again.

So my problem is : I have no idea how to stop this function once it is running.

Thank you for taking the time !